# Large MySQL table slow to query column with unique index

Tags: mysql

I have a large MySQL table (36 million rows, 120 GB) that is unable to handle a simple query on an column with a UNIQUE KEY. Ex:

```
select * from items where item_id = 12345;
```

Is there some reason why the index isn't helping here or am I just way beyond what MySQL can handle in terms of table size? Any pointers?

Edit: My table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_sku` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` varchar(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `subtitle` tinytext,
  `description` text,
  `category_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `itemId` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: @Drew I'm the only user of the DB at the moment. There may be a few locks hanging around from older queries, but probably not. The disk is kinda slower, on a SAN.

Comment: For a pure read on a table with not much else going on, shouldn't having the (unique) index be enough?

Comment: can you share a `show create table yourTable` for us

Comment: Do you need the `description` on that read

Comment: @Drew Added create statement. When I run that query, it never returns (I kill it after a few minutes). Checking on hardware (it's hosted elsewhere)...

Comment: @Drew I do not. Description may end up being a few K, but I'm only selecting a single record here (FWIW).

Comment: You dont have the service plan in that hosted environment to care for your needs. They aren't caring for your needs. Do you want one of us to set it up for you?

Comment: So, If I am not mistaken, isn't your indexed column the primary key?

Comment: @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram Ooops, just updated the original post. I'm querying by item_id, which is the UNIQUE KEY.

Comment: @Drew It's a side project on a friend's hardware. Tis what it is.

Comment: well when it becomes important, come back :p

Comment: @Drew you mean because it's a side project running on a friend's hardware, it's not important?

Comment: Josh, you seem to suggest the same. This is a side project for me too. Helping people for no gain.